# Changing default data fetcher behavior for graphql-java

Tags: graphql-java

I am doing a proof-of-concept project using graphql-java to implement the backend of a GraphQL interface. In my project, the persistence layer I am retrieving data from is a proprietary API that has map-like operations, and I would like to write custom data fetching logic against that proprietary API.

The runtime wiring for my root-level query looks something like the following:

```
RuntimeWiring wiring = newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("query", builder -> builder
        .dataFetcher("myQuery", new MyQueryFetcher()))
    .build();
```

The `get()` method currently returns an instance of a class called `PersistenceStore.Node`, and that object has map-like access methods that I can call in subsequent data fetchers. But I've been unable to get a data fetcher wired up right to handle those subsequent fetches.

With the above example, I'd like to have a query such as the following:

```
query {
  myQuery {
    id,
    name,
    description
  }
}
```

I would like the `MyQueryFetcher` class shown in the above runtime wiring return a `PersistenceStore.Node` instance. Then I'd like the references to `id`, `name`, and `description` fields to be resolved by another custom data fetcher implementation that I create.

I've tried adding a default data fetcher to my wiring:

```
RuntimeWiring wiring = newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("query", builder -> builder
        .defaultDataFetcher(new PersistenceStoreNodeFetcher())
        .dataFetcher("myQuery", new MyQueryFetcher()))
    .build();
```

but that doesn't appear to work - the `PersistenceSAtoreNodeFetcher` class's `get` method is never called.

I've been digging through the graphql-java documentation and source code but have not found anything yet.

Any idea how I can replace or customize the `PropertyDataFetcher` behavior with a fetcher of my own design?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the defaultDataFetcher is being applied to the query object, not to the object type returned by myQuery. What you probably need to do is to apply the defaultDataFetcher to the myQuery object type.

```
RuntimeWiring wiring = newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("query", builder -> builder
      .dataFetcher("myQuery", new MyQueryFetcher()))
    .type("myQueryResult")
      .defaultDataFetcher(new PersistenceStoreNodeFetcher())
    .build();
```

Comment: This approach is what I've been using to work around the problem, but it isn't a real solution. The problem is that I need to apply this default data fetcher for every single type that depend on it, and I have many of those types. What I was hoping for was a way to override the default property resolver to use my API rather than Java introspection.

Comment: Could you consider using a directive to do this? You'd need to annotate the SDL types, but at least you could avoid iterating through each type manually. Here's the docs, FWIW: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/master/sdl-directives/